# Value of has no member

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to get a CustomCell trough watching a Youtube Tutorial  but im getting this problem at my Tableview.It says 
Value of type 'CustomCell' has no member 'mainImage'. I hope some of you can help me to solve this problem.

The mainImage I want to get in my Cell is in my CustomCell.swift.

My TableViewController:

```
import UIKit

struct CellData {
    let image : UIImage?
    let message : String?

}

var data = [CellData]()

class TableViewController : UITableViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        data = [CellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Bildschirmfoto 2018-09-20 um 22.17.11"), message: "The Avengers")]
        self.tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "custom")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "custom") as! CustomCell
        cell.mainImage = data[indexPath.row].image
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        <#code#>
    }
}
```

My CustomCell

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

var message : String?
var mainImage : UIImage?

var messageView: UITextView = {
   var textView = UITextView()
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return textView
}()
var mainImageView: UIImageView = {
    var imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier)
        self.addSubview(mainImageView)
        self.addSubview(messageView)
        mainImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        mainImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        mainImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        mainImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        messageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo:mainImageView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        messageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        messageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        messageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.topAnchor).isActive = true

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if let message = message {
            messageView.text = message
        }
        if let image = mainImage {
            mainImageView.image = image
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you declaring all of those variables as globals instead of making them class properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your subviews **into** the cell class:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    var messageView: UITextView = {
        var textView = UITextView()
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return textView
    }()

    var mainImageView: UIImageView = {
        var imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()

    ...
}
```